# WebviewScaffold not scrolling when keyboard opens

Tags: flutter, dart, scroll, webviewscaffold

My WebviewScaffold in Flutter is not scrolling when keyboard opens. How would I be able to fix this?
Here is my code

```
WebviewScaffold(
          url: url,
          scrollBar: true,
          clearCache: false,
          clearCookies: false,
          withJavascript: true,
          geolocationEnabled: true,
          // run javascript
          withZoom: false,
          // if you want the user zoom-in and zoom-out
          hidden: false,
          // put it true if you want to show CircularProgressIndicator while waiting for the page to load
          appCacheEnabled: true,
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use some help from here, you the webview that is in this project:

https://github.com/npm-ued/flutter_webview_plugin

This issue has been [reported](https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter_webview_plugin/issues/128) and [fixed](https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter_webview_plugin/pull/690).

Answer (score 0):

```
Scaffold(
      body: ConstrainedBox(
        constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height),
        child: Container(
          child: <your widget>,

        ),
      ),
    )
```